# call a stored procedure multiple select query in entity framework code first and then map it to model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on a project using entity framework code first approach, I have a situation where I need to call a stored procedure which returns multiple table, hence I want to map the result to my model. please tell me if its possible to do it and if yes then how can i do it.

Comment: Show your code and stored procedure which you have implemented..

Comment: Are you looking for something like that  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx ?

Comment: Thank, i want to know if it works fine with code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code First currently only supports mapping to tables. This unfortunately means
that you can’t map Code First directly to stored procedures, views, or other database
objects. If you are letting Code First generate a database, there is no way to
create these artifacts in the database, other than manually adding them once Code
First has created the database. If you are mapping to an existing database, there
are some techniques you can use to get data from non-table database artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

i am also facing the same problem and not able to get any solution, so i called stored procedure using ExecuteReader and then mapped it to models using autoMapper.

Let me know if you are looking for code

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it